# Python error, only in the command window. Causes site to hang when loading

Tags: python, django

[image]

I receive this error when files are loading and sometimes after they have stopped loading. It only happens with this site, not with my other django sites. I can't make any sense of this one. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is too slow or it doesn't responds (networking problem, not a Python problem), that's what happens.

> only in the command window

?

Comment: I have other sites that run on the my dev server that don't have this problem. Doesn't that mean its the code?

Answer (score 1):

Too large an upload? Your front end interrupted the transfer somehow? Could be anything. We'll need more details to pin point the problem. Also, does this happen on your production setup?

Comment: When I had it on a production server a month back, I noticed the site would hang when loading. I assumed it was the server at fault, but now I think it may have been this funky error causing the trouble.

Comment: Unlikely. This is from the internal http server which wouldn't kick in when you're doing a deployment using `mod_wsgi` or whatever.